# Install Plotly ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, plotly

I am new to python notebook and python. I'm currently taking python for data science on LinkedIn learning, and I'm running into problem below and couldn't find the solution.

```
''''! pip3 install plotly''''
Collecting plotly
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/90/918bccb0ca60dc6d126d921e2c67126d75949f5da777e6b18c51fb12603d/plotly-4.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from plotly) (1.14.0)
Collecting retrying>=1.3.3 (from plotly)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/ef/beae4b4ef80902f22e3af073397f079c96969c69b2c7d52a57ea9ae61c9d/retrying-1.3.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: retrying, plotly
  Running setup.py install for retrying ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xz/w52k1b9n2935_w13djkjn9pc0000gn/T/pip-install-br5inttz/retrying/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xz/w52k1b9n2935_w13djkjn9pc0000gn/T/pip-install-br5inttz/retrying/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/xz/w52k1b9n2935_w13djkjn9pc0000gn/T/pip-record-w8sk2i31/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/xz/w52k1b9n2935_w13djkjn9pc0000gn/T/pip-install-br5inttz/retrying/
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    copying retrying.py -> build/lib
    running install_lib
    copying build/lib/retrying.py -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    error: could not create '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/retrying.py': Permission denied
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xz/w52k1b9n2935_w13djkjn9pc0000gn/T/pip-install-br5inttz/retrying/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xz/w52k1b9n2935_w13djkjn9pc0000gn/T/pip-install-br5inttz/retrying/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/xz/w52k1b9n2935_w13djkjn9pc0000gn/T/pip-record-w8sk2i31/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: It said: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/qqm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/retrying.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions

Comment: now `pip install plotly==4.6.0 --user` ?

Comment: Ohhh yeah it worked. thank you so much!

Comment: I will make it the answer so that you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pip install plotly==4.6.0 --user
```

https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/